# Google cache is not showing up for a page despite trying twice to use the fetch and render tool

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot, cache, google-cache

I did Fetch and Render twice on a particular page but the cached version of the page is still not showing up on Google.  I did a Fetch and Render on other posts on the site and they all showed cached versions within 24 hrs.

Haven't tried doing any change on the above post so not sure if Google is really crawling the page.

Comment: I removed your link to prevent your question from being closed. Anyone who wants to see the link can easily get to it through the edit history.

Comment: As well, fetch and render is not real time. It can take a while - several days in fact. The more you mess with it, the likelier Google will assume you are gaming the system. Leave it alone. You can check your log files to see if Google has fetched the page. Cheers!!

Comment: To double check. You are doing the Submit after the Fetch? The visible cache: is not 100% just like site: searches don't show everything. Not sure what the question heading has to do with the issue?

Comment: We have been getting tons of questions about Google cache not working properly for people's sites in the last few months.   I think something is wrong with the Google cache.